# How can I use jq to extract the value of href in this JSON snippet?

Tags: json, filtering, jq

I have an API returning JSON similar to the sample below

```
{
  "href": "https://www.mycompany.com/api/services/myservice/instances/service-instance-3",
  "id": "si-555aa555a555",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "node",
      "href": "https://www.mycompany.com/api/nodes/node-aa5a5a55"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to parse the value `https://www.mycompany.com/api/nodes/node-aa5a5a55` from the `links` array where the `rel` value is `node`.  How can I construct a `jq` filter to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this works
`jq -r '.links[] | select(.rel == "node") .href'`
I'm not sure of the pros/cons vs Hans' answer

Comment: You don't need to use `test` just use the direct string comparison, `.links[] | select(.rel == "node").href`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
jq -r '.links | map(select(.rel="node") | .href ) | first'
```

Comment: That works, I also had figured out that this worked also `jq -r '.links[] | select(.rel | test("node")) .href'`, any reason one is better than the other?

Comment: It seems using `first` handles a situation where there may be more than one object in the `links` array where `rel=node` and in that case it would just return a single result but in my case the API would only ever return a single object matching this condition